# How to detect <section> on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a website that has the menu created with FlexBox in HTML5, CSS3.

What I wanted to do as a SPA is that by going through such a section I "remarked" the menu button that takes me to that section.

I saw that there was this for example: http://www.miguelmanchego.com/2014/jquery-scroll-menu-detector-de-ubicacion/

But use `UL> Li`, I tried to adapt because I looked like a fool and I can not see what the error is.

**This is my menu:**

```
<section id="perfil">
    <img class="mi-foto" src="img/perfil.png">
    <nav>
        <div><a class="ripple grey" href="#sobre-mi"><span class="icono imagen-sobre-mi"></span><p>Sobre mi</p></a></div>
        <div><a class="ripple grey" href="#estudios"><span class="icono imagen-educacion"></span><p>Estudios</p></a></div>
        <div><a class="ripple grey" href="#cursos"><span class="icono imagen-experiencia-laboral"></span><p>Experiencia Laboral</p></a></div>
        <div><a class="ripple grey" href="#hobbies"><span class="icono imagen-hobbie"></span><p>Hobbies</p></a></div>
        <div><a class="ripple grey" href="#"><span class="icono imagen-portofolio"></span><p>Portofolio</p></a></div>
        <div class="redes">
            <div><a href="www.google.com.ar"><img src="img/redes-facebook.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="www.google.com.ar"><img src="img/redes-twitter.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="www.google.com.ar"><img src="img/redes-linkedin.png" alt=""></a></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

It is done with the waypoints.js library

Thank you, I'm looking forward for your answer!

Regards!

Comment: Please post in English on this site.

Comment: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Spanish site.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? detect if the `section` is in the window viewport?

Comment: Hi @MichaelCoker 
What I want to do
Have a fixed menu that I already have and it is done with flexbox
But when I go through each "section" that I select the button that "references" that section

Comment: I did something like that a while ago, here's a simple demo http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KVgEVV